# Neo4j Cypher Bus Route Selection

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am new to Cypher, I would like to know whether the following case is possible in Neo4j Cypher:

[image: bus route example]

When I want to query what the buses should be taken from Station 1 to Station 4, the output should be (which consists of least number of interchange):

1. Station 1 -> route 1 -> Station 3 -> route 3 -> station 4
2. Station 1 -> route 2 -> Station 3 -> route 3 -> station 4

But not every possible combinations:

1. Station 1 -> route 1 -> Station 2 -> route 1 -> Station 3 -> route 3 -> station 4
2. Station 1 -> route 1 -> Station 2 -> route 2 -> Station 3 -> route 3 -> station 4
3. Station 1 -> route 2 -> Station 2 -> route 1 -> Station 3 -> route 3 -> station 4
4. Station 1 -> route 2 -> Station 2 -> route 2 -> Station 3 -> route 3 -> station 4

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is difficult without conditional expressions (CASE/WHEN is now in 2.0). This is as close as I got in my few minutes of trying. You'd have to pull out the start nodes from the resulting relationship collection.

```
start st1=node:node_auto_index(name="station1"), st4=node:node_auto_index(name="station4") 
match p=st1-[r*]->st4 
with reduce(acc=[], route in rels(p): 
  case 
    when length(acc) > 0 and last(extract(a in acc: a.name)) = route.name then acc 
    else acc + route 
  end) as reducedRoutes 
return reducedRoutes, length(reducedRoutes) as len 
order by len;
```

http://console.neo4j.org/r/koe6fo

Comment: Thanks for your effort! You helped me a lot! It seems that it is hard to get this answer in the internet.

Comment: This is a valid solution, but when it comes to a large graph like http://gist.neo4j.org/?8748091 it does require an upper limit in the match, [*r1..10] or some good number.